# In dbpedia vocabulary, why is class "City" not linked with class "Country"?

Tags: linked-data

In dbpedia vocabulary, why is class "City" not linked with class "Country" ?

Answer (score 3):

I believe it is linked with Country through the `dbpedia-owl:country` link, have you looked at this?
[StackOverflow, query cities and their country](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15610033/query-cities-and-their-country-from-dbpedia)

Qoute sample code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?city ?country 
WHERE { ?city rdf:type dbpedia-owl:City ; 
              rdfs:label ?label ; 
              dbpedia-owl:country ?country 
}
```